# Python - ascii codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python

I am working on a bot for a Twitch.tv channel and one of the commands is supposed to work like this:

user inputs: !riot (text)

bot outputs: ヽ༼ຈل͜ຈ༽ﾉ(text) OR RIOT ヽ༼ຈل͜ຈ༽ﾉ

The problem is whenever someone tries to input the command an error gets displayed in the cmd window which says: "ascii codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)". Nothing is displayed in the chat.

I have the coding set to UTF-8 at the beginning of the file so i'm not sure why its giving me this error.

Heres the snippet of code for the command itself and the defining of doCommandProcess: http://imgur.com/a/R1G1e

Heres the snippet of code for the command and the defining of doCommandProcess in the previous version of the bot that works just fine: http://imgur.com/a/0tQpE

I'm just really confused because both versions are encoded with UTF-8 and have nearly identical code yet one refuses to work and gives me an ascii error.

EDIT: Heres the code in question:

```
def doCommandProcess( text, irc ):
    try:

        usernamearray = text.split('!')
        username = usernamearray[0]
        username = username[1:]

        messagearray = text.split(':')
        message = messagearray[2]

        if(len(usernamearray) >= 0 and len(messagearray) >= 2):

            sqlcommands.doCommand(message, irc)

            customcommands.docustomcommands(message, irc)

            print username + ": " + message

        if commandStartsWith(message, '!riot'):
            print len(message)
            if(len(message) > 8):
            riotmessage = message[6:]
            riotmessage = riotmessage.strip().upper()
                           respond(irc, 'ヽ༼ຈل͜ຈ༽ﾉ ' + riotmessage + ' OR RIOT ヽ༼ຈل͜ຈ༽ﾉ')
        else:
            respond(irc, 'You need to give a reason to riot!')

    except Exception,e:  
        #If an error happens
        #Print a new line for visibility
        print text
        print ""
        print str(e)
```

Comment: It's quite hard to read the code in those images. Please can you edit the code into your question?

Comment: Sure, should I edit the old code in below the new code as well?

Comment: you probably program in python2.7. you need to define unicode literal using `u` prefix.

Comment: Probably is detecting unicode... try using *text.encode('utf-8')*

Comment: That looks better, thanks. However, the code doesn't look like valid Python - the indentation is all over the place and there's a `try` block but no corresponding `except` block.

Comment: "I have the coding set to UTF-8 at the beginning of the file" -- that reflects the encoding of **the file** not string variables that happened to be named within it. Make sure you are using the **unicode** type and not old-school byte-strings.

Comment: @ajcr, my apologies, having to omit a lot of other commands caused me to miss the code at the very bottom. I fixed it, it should look fine now.

Answer (score 2):

So you're declaring the file to be parsed as unicode, but your strings still need to be declared as unicode strings. In order to do this, prefix the opening quotation mark with a lowercase `u`:

```
respond(irc, u'ヽ༼ຈل͜ຈ༽ﾉ ' + riotmessage + u' OR RIOT ヽ༼ຈل͜ຈ༽ﾉ')
```

You may want to be safe and ensure the riotmessage can be parsed properly by converting it unicode as well.

Comment: Ok I put in the "u's" but now i'm getting an error saying: `'ascii' can't encode characters in position 24-31: ordinal not in range(128)`

How would you go about converting it to Unicode?

Comment: @LittleGamie Did you add a u in front of the second string you have there (the one that starts with ` OR RIOT`)? Also, what is the content of riotmessage in the current failing example?

Comment: Yes, the content is: `respond(irc, u'ヽ༼ຈل͜ຈ༽ﾉ ' + riotmessage + u' OR RIOT ヽ༼ຈل͜ຈ༽ﾉ')` I'm testing it with "!riot test". Only the part test is what would be in riot message. So the output would be ヽ༼ຈل͜ຈ༽ﾉ TEST OR RIOT ヽ༼ຈل͜ຈ༽ﾉ

Comment: @LittleGamie Ah okay, it appears that whatever function you're calling requires an ascii string, so you should change what you're sending to: (u'ヽ༼ຈل͜ຈ༽ﾉ ' + riotmessage + u' OR RIOT ヽ༼ຈل͜ຈ༽ﾉ').encode('utf-8')

Comment: I tried that and now i'm getting an error message displaying: `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)` Position 9 is where the user input starts though with riotmessage. Weird its having a problem with that when "test" is just a normal phrase of letters.